# fetch message discord.py with ID being too long for an integer

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The discord library refuses to take my message IDs as string when I have no option to pass them as integer.

Okay so I want to get a message by it's ID in discord.py, the line of code I use for this is:
`msg = await channel.fetch_message(id=message_id)`
I also tried
`msg = await channel.fetch_message(id=int(message_id))`
Obviously the second one cannot work since discord message IDs are too long to be put in an integer, now the discord library only takes integers, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously the second one cannot work since discord message IDs are too long to be put in an integer

...did you try it...? Integers in Python aren't limited in size, unlike ints in languages like C or Java. The following works just fine:

```py
>>> int("108641816741441130410864181674144113041086418167414411304108641816741441130410864181674144113041086418167414411304")
108641816741441130410864181674144113041086418167414411304108641816741441130410864181674144113041086418167414411304
```

The docs say that a message ID is an integer, so you should be able to safely assume that you can pass in an integer. I don't see why you would "have no option to pass them as an integer".

The only limitation you have is that slash command parameters cannot exceed the integer size limit, so a slash param can not be an int if you want to pass in IDs. This is Discord-sided, not inside of your bot. Hence, when making the parameter a string, you can just manually cast it to an `int` internally without caring.

Comment: I did try to cast it to an int before in it's own line with message_id = int(message_id) and it threw an exception.

Comment: "it threw an exception" is not useful at all for me to help you solve it...

Comment: It failed in the typecast line where I was solely typecasting to an integer which I would assume is because integers are limited to a maximum of 2147483647 and discord message IDs are way larger numbers than that.

Comment: No, I mean show me the actual exception... And integers are **not** limited to `2147483647` in Python. My answer above very clearly shows an integer that is multiple billions of times larger than that and it works just fine.